# Create a custom form from Custom Content Type & Save it

Tags: 7, nodes, entities

I've created a custom *content-type* using GUI interface.

I need to customize the *form* which takes input while creating a content of the `content-type`. I can do this by `hook_theme` implementation *but* I'm trying to create a brand new form, and save the content's fields in database, so that it appears as a full-functional content of my `content-type`.

1. How do I create a form *(I know how to create forms in my custom module)* that contains the `fields` *(all, or selectively some)* of my custom *content-type*?
2. Most Importantly, when the form is submitted, how do I **save** the `fields` so that it appears as a brand new content-type?

*I think I've made it clear, please answer, or ask me to clarify the question more if necessary...*

Comment: I don't understand why you want do to it this way, but hook_form_alter seems to be the way to go, creating a custom entity in form_submit. Can you clarify your goal ? Because as it is, you seem to want to bypass Drupal to do exactly what it's conceived to do.

Comment: What if a single page in my website needs 2/3 forms to save 2/3 different content types? 

Can I use `hook_form_alter` to filter form fields per user roles or something like that?

Comment: Creating many content types with only one submit ? Are you sure you can't redesign your workflow to fit better in Drupal's default one ? And yes, you can filter fields in form_alter to customise their presence based on whatever condition you want, but IMHO you're heading for something which can quickly turn into implementation hell. Just thinking about the different submit functions and their logic makes me shiver.

Comment: I've different submit functions, different forms for each content types. Just displaying many forms in a page

Comment: If you don't mind multiple submits, then nothing can prevent you from having multiple forms on the same page, each handled separately by diffrent submit functions, as if they were on separated pages. By the way `hook_theme` doesn't belong in form logic, but in form presentation. You can output any form you want using `drupal_get_form` in your code.

Answer (score 1):

[node_form](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.pages.inc/function/node_form/7) will give you a form for your content-type, just pass a node.object having your content-type (*$node->type*) and maybe something more .., plus the content-type needs to be registred already i guess

saving is handled automagically ...